# c segmentation fault due to duplicacy in structure in functions

Tags: c, function, memory, segmentation-fault, structure

The program works fine for the first time , but if we want to add the details of another book, it gives segmentation fault after I enter the first attribute

```
int main()
{
    float count_tot=0,profit_tot=0;
    char option='y';
    fflush(stdin);
    struct book b;
    while(option!='n')
    {
        b=getinput();
        display(b);
        b.need= calcneed(b);
        b.profit=calcprofit(b);
        printf("Need To Order:%d\n",b.need);
        printf("Total Cost:%f\n",(b.need-b.qtyonhand)*b.price_sin);
        printf("do another book(Y/n)");
        scanf("%c",&option);
        option=getchar();
        count_tot+=(b.need-b.qtyonhand)*b.price_sin;
        profit_tot+=b.profit;
    }
    drawline();
    printf("TOTAL PROFIT:%f\n",profit_tot);
    printf("TOTAL COST:%f\n",count_tot);
    return(0);
}

struct book getinput
{
    struct book b;
    scanf("%d",&b.book_code);
    ...
    ...
} //the function contains a number of scanf functions
```

Comment: theindentatinoistoohorribletoeasilyfollowthecodeflow

Comment: Please post the definition of `struct book` and the complete code of `getinput`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a local variable in the function `getinput` and looking at the usage, you are returning it to the caller.  You will be better off passing the structure as a parameter and reading data into that structure.  The local copy of the structure is destroyed when the function terminates, unless you use dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Two things, when dealing with struct they should only be passed and returned as parameters to create fully portable code. Not all compilers can return struct types. Also you got a bug in main, you scanf %c into &option then next line reads option=getchar ();

Comment: thanks...and if I use either one of the statement...it is skipped and 'option' is initialised as newline character as it was already present in the buffer